# AuthenticationInterceptor in Alamofire - ignore for public requests

Tags: alamofire, interceptor

Is it possible to configure the AuthenticationInterceptor itself not to do a JWT refresh/check when the url contains e.g. `public`? I would like to always use the same Alamofire session and then within the interceptor check if a valid JWT is necessary or not

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

First, you can take the `AuthenticationInterceptor` code, copy it, and create your own version with the behavior you want.

Second, you can compose the `AuthenticationInterceptor` inside another interceptor (either your own or one of the provided interceptors), only calling into it under certain conditions.

Third, you can stop using the `AuthenticationInterceptor` with all requests through the `Session` and just attach it to particular requests. `request(..., interceptor:)` allows you to provide an interceptor on a per-request basis.